# What does $1a \in Hom(a, a)$ mean?

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to read Algebra, Chapter 0 by Aluffi.
In category section i found this sentence and cant find out what it exactly means.
So my question is:

What is meaning of this:  $1a ∈ Hom(a, a)$ ?

Comment: It probably says $1_A\in\mathrm{Hom}(A,A)$ and read "the identity morphism for object $A$ is a morphism from $A$ to $A$". It would be easier to give you an explanation at the level of detail you need if you provide some more of the context you found this sentence in.

Comment: I think you could have answered this question yourself had you but looked a few pages before (or paragraphs above?) to see what is the definition of $1_a$ and of $\hom(a,a)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning is that, for every object $a$ of the category, it is given a distinguished arrow (morphism) denoted by $1_a$ and called the identity of the object $a$. It is part of the definition of a category, so essentially you can only accept it. Note that the arrow $1_a$ has the same domain and codomain, namely the object $a$. Then you will see that $1_a$ must satisfy an axiom (unity axiom), and this of course for every $a$.